# CodeBuild get Artifact Folder Path

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, buildspec

I am running a build through a Codebuildpipeine.  I am uploading artifacts based on each stage as documented which is working fine.  As you know each time a build is run the artifact folder creates a new folder for the new set of artifacts (all in S3) to be uploaded.  What I want to do is retrieve the new folder name that is created in the Artifact folder into my buildspec so I can use it as a variable.  Does anyone have a link or a way I can reference this?  I would be willing to settle if I can get the entire URL where I can parse it?